# Microsoft Natural keyboard breaks Xbox 360 controller with some games

Tags: keyboard, xbox360

I have a Microsoft Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 and a standard Xbox 360 controller. I'm running Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

When I plug in the keyboard, Windows automatically installs some drivers and starts the itype.exe process in the background. This appears to break the controller compatibility in some games. Note that all of these games work fine if I unplug the keyboard before launching them.

**Games that work**

- Onlive
- Jamestown
- Dustforce
- EDGE
- Dungeon Defenders
- [Outcast](http://www.gog.com/gamecard/outcast) (If anything should have broken, it's this. It's ancient! Why didn't it?)

**Games that don't**

- Altitude
- Rayman 3

My guess is that the [Zoom toggle](http://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000#details) on the keyboard is acting like a joystick axis somehow? But I really have no idea. Is there anything I can do about this other than removing the keyboard before playing those games?

Comment: I don't know what to say, I have a similar Microsoft keyboard, and I have installed the itype.exe application and have no problems with games.  Of course through my own experience I use Xpadder to have support with virtually any game.

Comment: @Ramhound Altitude has a free demo on Steam. Could you try it out and see if your Xbox controller works in it with the keyboard connected? Also, what version of Windows are you running?